# IBM Worklight adapter using security tests

Tags: forms-authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, realm, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I'm using Workilight version 6.0 and I'm trying to use a security test with Workilght's adapter.
First of all, I developed a login page and home page where I'll display some informations after the user will be authenticated.
The authentication seems to be OK because I'm getting the user information and session Id which I'll sent in the cookie of the next HTTP adapter using the security test.

The problem is that I'm getting NullPointerException from the specified adapter but when I execute the request with RestClient, I get the response so the WS is OK.

Any body have an idea about how to that ?

PS: my code was working on worklight V5.0 but not with V6.0

Comment: Can you add the exception or errors?

Comment: Thank you Adan for your interest, I wasn't able to add comment, Now I am. The problem was du to the Web service. Otherwise you have to be sure that there are no additional security test like "MobileSecurityTest" added in the "authenticationConfig.xml" file because it may causes the same issue.

Comment: So I understand you've solved this? Please write it as an Answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by deleting non useful Security Test like "MobileSecurityTest". 
So before testing your adapter make sure that your declaration in the "authenticationConfig.xml" file is well done.
For more information about that, you can visit this URL :

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/08_03_Adapter_based_authentication.pdf

In addition, you have to figure out the root response in the adapter response to see first how looks your received data, otherwise you may be will receive a "NullPointerException" as response if you attempt to get for example "response.result" and the attribut "result" doesn't exist.

Hope that help you for future issues like I got.